# JwtSecurityToken in .NET 8

Tags: jwt, .net-8.0

I use JWT for my project authentication.

I used .NET 7 and the code shown here works for me correctly.

This code is used for checking if a token exists in the database:

```
if (!(context.SecurityToken is JwtSecurityToken accessToken) ||
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken.RawData) ||
    !await tokenStoreService.IsValidTokenAsync(accessToken.RawData, userId))
{
    context.Fail("This token is not in our database.");
    return;
}
```

but when I upgrade my .NET version to 8, now this code doesn't work anymore.

I searched and I found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events), I don't know it's relevant to my question or not.

Comment: _"now this code doesn't work anymore."_ **How** is it not working anymore? Do you get an exception? Does the `if` guard's expression evaluate to `false`? Do you suddenly get [Nasal Demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)?

Comment: FWIW, checking a database to validate a security-token or session on every request is an anti-pattern and defeats the whole point of using bearer-token schemes like JWT (which is that they enable stateless (and scalable) architecture because the RPs (sites that receive JWTs from clients) can _trust_ the issuer of the JWTs (the IdP)). Please reconsider your architecture and think about the problems you're trying to solve here...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I searched and [I found this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/8.0/securitytoken-events), I don't know it's relevant to my question or not.

It is.

The article says that **previously** (in ASP.NET Core 7), the `TokenValidatedContext.SecurityToken` property would return a [`JwtSecurityToken` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytoken?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest); but now it [returns a `JsonWebToken` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens.jsonwebtoken?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest).

i.e.:

|  | ASP.NET Core 7 | ASP.NET Core 8 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `JwtBearerEvents.SecurityToken` returns: | `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.` `JwtSecurityToken` | `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.` `JsonWebToken` |

So this code won't work anymore:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

TokenValidatedContext ctx = ...
if( ctx.SecurityToken is JwtSecurityToken jwt )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "farts" );
}
```

You need to change it to test for the new type instead (and remove any references to the now-supplanted `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll` library):

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens;

TokenValidatedContext ctx = ...
if( ctx.SecurityToken is JsonWebToken jwt )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "new and improved farts" );
}
```

---

- In your case, you should change your code as follows (*and* make it more readable by not combining 3 different things in a single `if`):

  - Also, the `JwtSecurityToken.RawData` property does not seem to have an equivalent in `JsonWebTokens` *unless* it's the [ominously named `UnsafeToString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.jsonwebtokens.jsonwebtoken.unsafetostring?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest).
- But I note that the whole point of using JWTs is that applications can *delegate trust* so they shouldn't need to verify JWTs themselves beyond cheap-and-quick cryptographic signature verification (so especially nothing as expensive as a round-trip DB lookup!) so something is amiss with your application's design...

  - And if `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken.RawData)` then `context.SecurityToken` would also be `null` and your `tokenStoreService.IsValidTokenAsync` would have to return `false` - so it's doubly-redundant.

```
if( context.SecurityToken is JsonWebToken jwt )
{
    #warning You probably shouldn't need to do any of this:
    String rawJwt = jwt.UnsafeToString();
    Boolean isValid = await tokenStoreService.IsValidTokenAsync( rawJwt, userId, cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if( !isValid )
    {
        context.Fail("This token is not in our database.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use the property `String rawJwt = jwt.EncodedToken;`. The method 'UnsafeToString()' returns RawData in the old JwtSecurityToken and returns EncodedToken in the new JsonWebToken.

But I also second the recommendation that usually you check tokens via signature, and not by database lookup. The raw token will also include things like issued at time (iat), so quickly be outdated.